# jQuery - Iterate only once in a nested each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach, each

I have been trying to iterate through a set of list items in each section only once. That is, on scrolling to a particular section, I want a set of list items to iterate just once. This should not repeat on continuous scrolling.

The code I wrote iterates through each section and also through each list item in the section, but it continues on each scroll.

I want this to iterate through each section only once.

```
   $(window).scroll(function(){
          var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
           $('body section').each(function(e){
            if($(this).position().top < windscroll){
              $(this).find(".inner-skills li").each(function(i){
              $(this).delay(i*500).animate({
                "width":"200px",
                "opacity":1
              },500);

              });
            }
          }) 
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) it:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   $('body section').each(function(e){
      if($(this).position().top < windscroll){
         $(this).find(".inner-skills li").each(function(i){
            $(this).delay(i*500).animate({
               "width":"200px",
               "opacity":1
            },500);
         });
      }
   }) 
   $(window).unbind('scroll');
});
```

EDIT:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   $('body section').not('.completed').each(function(e){ //Loop through all sections WITHOUT class of completed
      if($(this).position().top < windscroll){
         $(this).find(".inner-skills li").each(function(i){
            $(this).delay(i*500).animate({
               "width":"200px",
               "opacity":1
            },500);
         });
         $(this).addClass('completed'); // add class of completed so it wont loop through this anymore
      }
   }) 
});
```

Comment: This does not work. On unbinding, none of the sections are iterated. The problem with my code is that, even on the completion of animation, on scrolling the events are fired which would be unnecessary computation. I want to iterate through each section only once. And each section has a set of list items which has to be iterated only once!

Comment: Edited the answer based on new understanding from your comment. Please try now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to check if you have already scrolled or not

try this:

```
 var already_scrolled = 0;
 $(window).scroll(function(){
      if(already_scrolled == 0){
      already_scrolled = 1;
      var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
       $('body section').each(function(e){
             if($(this).position().top < windscroll){
                $(this).find(".inner-skills li").each(function(i){
                $(this).delay(i*500).animate({
                   "width":"200px",
                   "opacity":1
                },500);

               });
             }
      }) 
      }
    });
```

Comment: Very cool! I was unaware that .each() had a built-in counter.

Comment: _I want this to iterate through each section only once._ - this will only get to the first section, not iterate through them once...

Comment: What happens on doing this is that I would be able to iterate only through the first section! Not after that.

Comment: Edit answer with another solution. try now please @AdhithyaKumar